# Does Windows expect to be first in the drive order?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-8

I am combining a Linux SSD and a Windows HDD into the same system. Does Windows always expect to be first in drive order? I've named my Linux drive 'sda', which I believe means it is first. Will there be a conflict here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your physical connections doesn't really matter because the boot device is selected in the BIOS. If you have 2 physically separate drives you can choose which bootloader to use.

If you point your BIOS to the Linux SSD then you will need to add Windows to the GRUB menu if you want to be able to select the Windows OS without changing the BIOS.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274881/how-to-add-windows-to-grub

If you point the BIOS to your Windows HDD then you need to add the Linux install to your Windows Boot Loader:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader

You could do both of these options and then either way the computer boots you will see a menu to select the OS.